# Difference between @RibbonClient and @LoadBalanced

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

I understand `@LoadBalanced` indicates the Rest template should be based on Client Side Load Balancing using Ribbon and checks Eureka server for resolving the service name to host/port.

What is the use of `@RibbonClient`. Is it to support native Ribbon Client LB without Eureka and also support Eureka Discover when configured with `DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `@LoadBalanced` is a marker annotation & `@RibbonClient` is used for configuration purposes.

---

### `@LoadBalanced`

Used as a marker annotation indicating that the annotated `RestTemplate` should use a `RibbonLoadBalancerClient` for interacting with your service(s).

In turn, this allows you to use "logical identifiers" for the URLs you pass to the `RestTemplate`. These logical identifiers are typically the name of a service. For example:

```java
restTemplate.getForObject("http://some-service-name/user/{id}", String.class, 1);
```

where `some-service-name` is the logical identifier.

### `@RibbonClient`

Used for configuring your Ribbon client(s).

**Is @RibbonClient required?**

No! If you're using Service Discovery and you're ok with all of the default Ribbon settings, you don't even need to use the `@RibbonClient` annotation.

**When should I use `@RibbonClient`?**

There are at least two cases where you need to use `@RibbonClient`

1. You need to customize your Ribbon settings for a particular Ribbon client
2. You're not using any service discovery

***Customizing your Ribbon settings:***

Define a `@RibbonClient`

```java
@RibbonClient(name = "some-service", configuration = SomeServiceConfig.class)
```

- `name` - set it to the same name of the service you're calling with Ribbon but need additional customizations for how Ribbon interacts with that service.
- `configuration` - set it to an `@Configuration` class with all of your customizations defined as `@Beans`. Make sure this class **is not** picked up by `@ComponentScan` otherwise it will override the defaults for ALL Ribbon clients.

See the section "Customizing the RibbonClient` in the Spring Cloud Netflix documentation [(link)](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-netflix.adoc#customizing-the-ribbon-client)

***Using Ribbon without Service Discovery***

If you're not using Service Discovery, the `name` field of the `@RibbonClient` annotation will be used to prefix your configuration in the `application.properties` as well as "logical identifier" in the URL you pass to `RestTemplate`.

Define a `@RibbonClient`

```java
@RibbonClient(name = "myservice")
```

then in your `application.properties`

```
myservice.ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
myservice.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:5000, http://localhost:5001
```

Comment: If client application communicates with multiple services through restTemplate, how to declare separate RibbonClient for each service. For context, I have an endpoint in Controller which calls two methods of two Service classes. Each of these service methods calls for ex.: restTemplate.getForObject("http://service-name1/api, Employee.class") and restTemplate.getForObject("http://service-name2/api, Employee.class"). How to define RibbonClient for 'service-name1' and 'service-name2'. Per examples, there is an option to declare only one RibbonClient in the main class SpringBootApplication

Comment: Thanks Dustin, this was the best and to the point explanation.

Answer (score 8):

`RestTemplate` supports load balancing, using `@LoadBalanced`  tells Spring Cloud that we want to take advantage of its load balancing support(If you are using Ribbon then the effect of using @LoadBalanced will be that RestTemplate will use RibbionClient to get the server address).

 
You can also check how LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration works [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/loadbalancer/LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration.java)

Using [@RibbonClients](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/RibbonClient.java) you can provide declarative configuration for a ribbon client.

E.g.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RibbonClient(name = "app", configuration = RibbonConfig.class)
public class App {

  @LoadBalanced
  @Bean
  RestTemplate restTemplate(){
    return new RestTemplate();
  }
  //...
}
```

Then you create `RibbonConfig.class` to override any Ribbon related bean.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.IPing;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.IRule;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.PingUrl;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.AvailabilityFilteringRule;

public class RibbonConfig {

  @Autowired
  IClientConfig ribbonClientConfig;

  @Bean
  public IPing ribbonPing (IClientConfig config) {
    return new PingUrl();//we override default Iping which is a NoOpPing
  }

  @Bean
  public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
    return new AvailabilityFilteringRule(); // we override the default ZoneAvoidanceRule
  }

}
```