# File upload spring cloud feign client

Tags: java, microservices, spring-cloud, multipart, feign

When make a post request from one microservice to another using feign client of spring cloud netflix, I get the following error in Postman :

```
{
"timestamp": 1506933777413,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "feign.codec.EncodeException",
"message": "Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile[\"inputStream\"]->java.io.FileInputStream[\"fd\"])",
"path": "/attachments"
}
```

And my eclipse console shows the following exception :

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class java.io.FileDescriptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile["inputStream"]->java.io.FileInputStream["fd"])
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:284) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.mappingException(SerializerProvider.java:1110) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportMappingProblem(SerializerProvider.java:1135) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:69) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:32) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:689) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:689) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:292) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1429) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:951) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:2.8.9]

**UPDATE 1**

This is my  feign interface :

```
@FeignClient(name="attachment-service", fallback=AttachmentHystrixFallback.class)
public interface AttachmentFeignClient {

@RequestMapping("upload")
void upload(@RequestPart(name="file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(name="attachableId") Long attachableId, 
        @RequestParam(name="className") String className, @RequestParam(name="appName") String appName);
```

And this is the main microservice controller :

```
@RestController
public class AttachmentController implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4431842080646836475L;

@Autowired
AttachmentService attachmentService;

@RequestMapping(value = "attachments", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void upload(@RequestPart MultipartFile file, @RequestParam Long attachableId, @RequestParam String className, @RequestParam String appName) throws Exception {
    attachmentService.uploadFile(file, attachableId, className, appName);
}

}
```

I'm certainly missing some kind of serializer here
Any suggestion would be appreciated ! 
Thanks

Comment: are the pojos on those 2 microservices identical? If their fields and name matches, you should not need any serializer. Show a snipped of your code with rest defined in one service, and the same method in your feinclient interface

Comment: @mlecz yes all the pojos are located in a starter which is integrated in both microservices

Comment: @mlecz take a look at the update 1 please

Comment: those 2 look simillar. No idea how to help you. I see you updated this post again, but before update I saw 2 methods linked to attachements url, one get, one post. Maybe try adding RequestMapping.get to feign client?

Comment: I found a solution by adding some dependencies for feign form ..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After few days searching a solution I found this. You should start to add feign form for spring dependency :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.openfeign.form</groupId>
   <artifactId>feign-form-spring</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency
```

Then your feign client need this spring form encoder :

```
@FeignClient(
    name="attachment-service",  
    configuration = {AttachmentFeignClient.MultipartSupportConfig.class}
    fallback=AttachmentHystrixFallback.class)
public interface AttachmentFeignClient {

@RequestMapping(value= {"upload"}, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
void upload(
    @RequestPart(name="file") MultipartFile file, 
    @RequestParam(name="attachableId") Long attachableId, 
    @RequestParam(name="className") String className,
    @RequestParam(name="appName") String appName);

 public class MultipartSupportConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Encoder feignFormEncoder() {
        return new SpringFormEncoder();
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: Hey Martin, I did the same config as you but I am getting "Required request part 'file' is not present" have you seen this error?

Comment: because of the upload method  set a parameter "file" , so you must set the file filed named "file"

Answer (score 9):

**Update 13/01/2020** 
 **Configure FeignClient to handle MultiPartFile with @RequestPart** 
Note that this approach is suitable only if you have *one* RequestPart that represents the whole body.  Having multiple RequestPart is another problem with FeignClient.

---

The configuration of the feignclient is similar to what @marting-choraine did, but by adding the extra Encoder Configuration in the FeignConfigurationClass.

So with the same example that I provide below, instead of implementing a custom mapper, you will need to do something like this

```java
@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "YourPackage")
public class FeignConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Encoder feignFormEncoder(ObjectFactory<HttpMessageConverters> messageConverters) {
      return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(messageConverters));
  }
}
```

**TL;DR** 
**Transform your MultiPartFile to MultiValueMap. See example below**

---

The answer mentioned by [@martin-choraine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4467001/martin-choraine) is the proper and the best answer to have your FeignClient method signature, the same as the actual endpoint signature that you are trying to call. However, there is a way around that does not require you to define a FormEncoder or add any extra dependency because in some applications you are not allowed to do that (enterprise shit); all what you need is to transform your MultipartFile to a MultiValueMap and it will perfectly work as the standard encoder will be able to serialize it.

---

**Actual EndPoint to be called**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/add", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public MyResponseObject add(@RequestParam(name = "username") String username,
                             @RequestPart(name = "filetoupload") MultipartFile file) {
              Do something
}
```

**The POST method in your FeignClient should look like this**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/myApi/add", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, 
              produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public MyResponseObject addFile(@RequestParam(name = "username") String username,
                           @RequestPart(name = "filetoupload") MultiValueMap<String, Object> file);
```

**Then when you call the addFile you should provide MultiValueMap like this**

```
public MyResponseObject addFileInAnotherEndPoint(String username, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    ByteArrayResource contentsAsResource = new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()) {
        @Override
        public String getFilename() {
            return file.getOriginalFilename();
        }
    };
    multiValueMap.add("filetoupload", contentsAsResource);
    multiValueMap.add("fileType", file.getContentType());
    return this.myFeignClient.addFile(username, multiValueMap);
}
```

Comment: any idea how to implement the same for Multiple files? I checked your comments on GitHub too. I tried `FeignSpringFormEncoder` but it now throws `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.BufferedInputStream` .

Comment: @MohammedIdris I actually never been a situation where I need to send a list of files. However, when I was looking for my problem there was this library [FormEncoder](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-form). Also, this stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212557/uploading-a-list-of-multipartfile-with-spring-4-resttemplate-java-client-rest) may help you.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working,found another [FeignEncoder](https://github.com/pcan/feign-client-test/blob/master/src/main/java/it/pcan/test/feign/client/FeignSpringFormEncoder.java) which didn't encode the request with bodyType. I have tried with restTemplate which requires more code to be written as compared to Feign, however, I have the other microservice(the one that takes images and processes them) on a eureka discovery. If I can somehow connect RestTemplate via eureka it would be enough for now. I do not want to mention port number and url in the url param of rest (if that's possible)

Comment: By not working I mean the `encode` method in `Encoder` class throws `NPE`. I could post the error in **github openFeign** but i decided to take restTemplate approach with async calls for each image which I realised is a better approach.

I tried to resolve feign error but due to lack of prior experience and fewer examples on net I could not resolve the error. I tried commenting on other github issues but no response yet. 

I am new to microservices, if anyone could point me to example(s) where eureka client name is used in restTemplate it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For your question regarding "Resolving services identifiers from Eureka client", I think what you need is "load balancing" specifically @LoadBalanced from spring cloud. Look at this stackOverFlow question[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587317/difference-between-ribbonclient-and-loadbalanced) explaining LoadBalanced vs RibbonClient, dig more into the details and you will hopefully get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

i have added  consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE  in the post and it works for me.
 this is my feign client method and in the front i worked with formdata

```
@PostMapping(path=Urls.UPLOAD_FILE_IN_LIBELLE, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )
    public void uploadFileInLibelle(
            @RequestParam String processus,
            @RequestParam String level0Name,
            @RequestParam String nomFichier,
            @RequestParam String nomLibelle,
            @RequestParam String anneeFolderName,
            @RequestParam String semaineFolderName,
            @RequestPart   MultipartFile fichier);
```

this is my angular frontent

```
public uploadFiles(
        nomFichier: string,
        nomLibelle: string,
        processus: string,
        level0Name: string,
        semaineFolderName: string,
        anneeFolderName: string,
        byte: File
    ): Observable<any> {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.set('processus', processus);
        formData.set('level0Name', level0Name);
        formData.set('nomLibelle', nomLibelle);
        formData.set('anneeFolderName', anneeFolderName);
        formData.set('semaineFolderName', semaineFolderName);
        formData.set('nomFichier', nomFichier);
        formData.set('fichier', byte);

        return this.httpClient.post(this.urlUploadFile, formData);
    }
```